# ¿Cómo almaceno el ultimo valor que se genero con números aleatorios en un array C++?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Tengo que generar un array de N elementos. Y después llenarlo hasta la mitad con números al azar
menores a 800. ¿Cómo hago para almacenar el ultimo valor generado?

```
for(int i=0; (i<(n/2)); i++){       
    array[i]=rand()%800;   
    cout<<"Numeros al azar menores a 800: "<<endl<<array[i]<<"\n";
```

Comment: Genera una lista de 800 números, del 0 al 799, la [barajas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Fisher-Yates) y tomas los primeros N/2 valores. Eso es todo. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Y como almaceno el ultimo valor generado en una variable tipo int?

Answer (score 2):

Se puede lograr accediendo al elemnto n/2-1 del array después de haber generado los números:

```
    for(int i=0; (i<(n/2)); i++){       
        array[i]=rand()%800;   
        cout<<"Numeros al azar menores a 800: "<<endl<<array[i]<<"\n";
    }
    int variable = array[n/2-1];
```

Si lo quieres hacer dentro del bucle simplemente con un if se podría hacer lo siguiente:

```
int variable;
for(int i=0; (i<(n/2)); i++){       
    array[i]=rand()%800;
    if(i==n/2-1) variable=array[i];   
    cout<<"Numeros al azar menores a 800: "<<endl<<array[i]<<"\n";
}
```